# Having difficulties extending Zend_Form

Tags: zend-framework, inheritance, zend-form, subclass

Currently I have big difficulties extending Zend_Form.

I have the basic class called **Forms_LpaManageEmailForm**.
It is used separately and works fine.
Next I've created a new class form
called **Default_Form_CartReport** witch extends **Forms_LpaManageEmailForm**.
So the task is to render **Default_Form_CartReport** and slitely modificate it. 
In other words I need all functionality of
**Forms_LpaManageEmailForm** class but with overriden `_addMultiOptionsForMultiSelect()` function
(what is done) and changed button label (doesn't solved).

In basic class I have hidden element named **id** which value is filled with 
`$this->_entry_id['entry_id'].` When I use basic form separately - its woks fine. But
when I run extended form(Forms_LpaManageEmailForm) I see that hidden id element's value is empty. In basic class in construct section I run
Zend debugger(with this line `Zend_Debug::dump($this->_entry_id['entry_id'])`) to see if the
value is passed. And it's passed :) When I repeat this in init() section it shows NULL...

As I barely understand - the problem lays in init() functions, in the way it is called. 
I think something is wrong with Default_Form_CartReport class skeleton.

I've uploaded code to: [PASTEBIN](http://pastebin.com/Wn1iafG2)
Really need help in this question.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issues are causing my the fact that `Forms_LpaManageEmailForm:: __construct` is calling `$this->init()` directly. if you open the `Zend_Form`, you will notice that the `__construct` is also calling the  `$this->init()`  function. This cause your `init()` function to executed twice.

Try to load all your logic & elements solely in the `__construct` function, and don't use the `init()` function. also, the `__construct` function in each form class should always call the `parent::__construct` before any additional logic.

Comment: **aporat**, thank you very much for your answer! I've updated my code, now its here: [LINK](http://pastebin.com/DPJxv7U5). Now when I run `Zend_Debug::dump($this->getElements())` it writes that id element have `["_value":protected] => int(51)` value. But still doesn't it output in HTML... Now I can change labels :)  I think we are on a right way for a final solution

Comment: Additionally I've added data from `Zend_Debug::dump($this->getElements())`

Comment: By they way: if I remove the id element from parent class - the child form won't be rendered at all. But I can see form dump... Very strange behaviour

Comment: Finally got it. The final problem was in controller isValid method... Currently fixing it :)

Comment: no problem :-). btw, the   addElement() function returns you the element itself, so you can write something like that:   $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit'); $submit->setLabel('Submit');$this->addElement($submit);